# Rendering a marker "on top of everything" (including whatever is rendered in floatPane)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a case when there is a number of points on the map and each of them has a "tooltip", that is always shown, which is implemented as a div, that's rendered in (onto?) floatPane, which means, that these divs are rendered above everything. I have a marker, that must not be occluded by these divs, but as of now, it is rendered in overlayImage pane.

What would be th most painless way to make it appear on top of everything? It also has to be able to receive mouse events (click, dragdrop).

Comment: Can you provide some sample code demonstrating the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase `z-index` property.

This can be done by two ways.

In marker properties:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng, 
            map: map, 
            title:"Hello World!",
            zIndex: 1000
});
```

After initializing marker:

```
marker.setZIndex(1000);
```

Comment: This should not work (I've tried a very similar approach). Thing is, as I understand, z-indices are considered only within a given pane. No matter how high you set it, whatever is in floatPane will occlude everything else.